# Capture touch on UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, uinavigationbar

I am trying to capture a touch event on my `UINavigationBar`.  When a user taps it, I'm planning to perform an action.  However, I do not seem to be able to capture touch events on this component.  My code looks like this...

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.navigationController.navigationBar action:nil];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Whenever I tap the navigation bar, though, my selector is not called.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Do I need to do something special to capture touch events on this control?

Comment: Check the target of the singleTape. Take a look on @Gabriel.Massana answer

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer  initWithTarget should be "self" and provide action as well

Comment: The answer is helpful for you? Then why you don't accept it and vote up?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
//singleTap.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];



-(void) doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"doSomething");
}
```

- Target should be self (the recipient of the action)
- Action should be the selector that identifies the method implemented